# In kartik/gridview of yii2 export link is not display its shows the #?

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have written following code for export data as csv or other format using kartik/gridview plugin in yii2. When i click on export button its display # sign on each type of export so hot fix this issue.

index.php

```
    <?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\grid\GridView;
    use yii\widgets\Pjax;
    use app\models\AdminUserMaster;
    use yii\helpers\Url;
    use app\models\SubAdminRoles;
    use kartik\export\ExportMenu; 
/* This code for design coloumns */
                        $gridColumns = [
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                            'full_name',
                            'email',
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                        ];

/* This code create export menu */
    echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
         'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK,
        'fontAwesome' => true,
        'dropdownOptions' => [
            'label' => 'Export All',
            'class' => 'btn btn-default'
        ]]);

/* This code create a gridview with column and data with action and number column */
    echo \kartik\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
         'responsive' => true,
            'hover' => true,
            'bordered' => false,
            'floatHeader' => true,
                    'pjax' => true,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,]);

    ?>
/* This code will configured the gridview module */
```

web.php file

```
    'modules' => [            
                    'gridview' => [
                    'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
                    //'downloadAction' => 'export',
                    'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
                    ]

    So please help me how to fix this issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create export options for csv like this.

```
GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'kv-grid-vehicle',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
        'columns'=>$gridColumns,
        'resizableColumns'=>true,
        'containerOptions'=>['style'=>'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
        'headerRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'filterRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'pjax'=>true, // pjax is set to always true for this demo
        'export'=>[
            'fontAwesome'=>true
        ],
        // parameters from the demo form
        'bordered'=>true,
        'striped'=>false,
        'condensed'=>true,
        'responsive'=>false,
        'hover'=>true,
        'showPageSummary'=>false,
        'panel'=>[
            'type'=>GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,            
        ],
        'persistResize'=>false,
        'exportConfig'=>$defaultExportConfig,
    ]);
    ?>
```

and $defaultExportConfig like this

```
$defaultExportConfig = [    
    GridView::CSV => [
        'label' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'CSV'),
        'icon' => $isFa ? 'file-code-o' : 'floppy-open', 
        'iconOptions' => ['class' => 'text-primary'],
        'showHeader' => true,
        'showPageSummary' => true,
        'showFooter' => true,
        'showCaption' => true,
        'filename' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'grid-export'),
        'alertMsg' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'The CSV export file will be generated for download.'),
        'options' => ['title' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Comma Separated Values')],
        'mime' => 'application/csv',
        'config' => [
            'colDelimiter' => ",",
            'rowDelimiter' => "\r\n",
        ]
    ],
]
```

may this help you.